# Finding the mode of floating point arrays in MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab, mode

I have an array of about 25,000 4-D vectors that vary around
`[1 .001 .0015 .0000010434]`.

I'm trying to find the mode of the vectors. I've tried MatLab's built-in `mode()` function, but I get a result of `1 0 0 0`. Could it be that because the decimals are so small that MatLab's `mode()` function rounds to a certain decimal point, resulting in 0? Is there a way to bypass this? I've also read about `histc()`'s functionality, but don't understand how I can reach my goal using it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique` to find repetition number of each row in its result:

```
 % A is a  25000 * 4 matrix
 [C,~,ic] = unique(A,'rows'); % find unique rows
```

in the above, `ic` shows the index of the rows. Hence, the mode of these can determine the most repetitive vector:

```
 modeRow = A(mode(ic),:);
```